# sed print more than one matches in a line

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file, including some strings and variables, like:

```
 ${cat.mouse.dog}
 bird://localhost:${xfire.port}/${plfservice.url}
 bird://localhost:${xfire.port}/${spkservice.synch.url}
 bird://localhost:${xfire.port}/${spkservice.asynch.request.url}
 ${soabp.protocol}://${hpc.reward113.host}:${hpc.reward113.port}
${configtool.store.folder}/config/hpctemplates.htb
```

I want to print all the strings between "{}". In some lines there are more than one such string and in this case they should remain in the same line. The output should be:

```
cat.mouse.dog
xfire.port plfservice.url
xfire.port spkservice.synch.url
xfire.port spkservice.asynch.request.url
soabp.protocol hpc.reward113.host hpc.reward113.port
configtool.store.folder
```

I tried the following:

```
sed -n 's/.*{//;s/}.*//p' filename
```

but it printed only the last occurrence of each line. How can I get all the occurrences, remaining in the same line, as in the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not against `awk`, you can try the following:

```
 awk -v RS='{|}' -v ORS=' ' '/\n/{printf "\n"} (NR+1)%2' file
```

The record separator `RS` is set to either `{` or `}`. This splits the wanted pattern from the rest.

The script then displays 1 record out of 2 with the statement `(NR+1)%2`.

In order to keep the alignment as expected, the output record separator is set to a space `ORS=' '` and everytime a newline is encountered this statement `/\n/{printf "\n"}` inserts one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed. :-) awk is perfect. I couldn't find a solution for 2 days, so I'm very thankful.

Comment: Now I'd like to run a script for all variables of the same file. The script is done and it' s to resolve the variables to get their values. Let's call the script resolve.sh. 
I'd like to go through the file and where there is a string between "{}", let the script run. Something like 
    cat file | for i in `awk -v RS='{|}' -v ORS=' ' '/\n/{printf "\n"} (NR+1)%2'`; do resolve.sh $i; done
Of course my "solution" is wrong because it gives only the resolved value of the variable, each one is a separated line. I'd like to have the original file but where there is a variable, let resolve.sh run.

Comment: If i understand well and you want to loop through all matching pattern, you can use this: `for i in $(awk -v RS='{|}' -v ORS=' ' '(NR+1)%2' test); do resolve.sh $i; done`

Comment: Yes, this is how I get the resolved values. But I'd like to get an output including the original file, where the variables are substituted by the resolved values.
E.g. original file:
bird://localhost:${xfire.port}/${plfservice.url}
Output should look like:
bird://localhost:8043/net-littlecat-rbp
How do I print the content of the original file and loop through all matching pattern where there is a variable?

Comment: You'd better create a new post since this deviates from the original question.

Comment: Done with the following title:
"Loop through all matching pattern, leaving the original string for the rest"

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/${/\n/g;T;s/[^\n]*\n\([^}]*\)}[^\n]*/\1 /g;s/ $//p' file
```

Replace all `${` by newlines and if there are non then move on as there is nothing to process. If there are newlines then remove non-newline characters to the left and non-newline characters to the right of the next `}` globally. To finish off remove the extra space introduced in the RHS of the global substitution.

Comment: This is also perfect, just like the above awk solution. Thanks for both.